# Grouping list within a list of list based on first element

Tags: python

I have a list containing:

```
lst = [[5, 2], [4, 7], [3, 5]]
```

and i want to rearrange them as such:

```
[[3,5],[4,7],[5,2]]
```

the problem I'm having is to arrange them such that the list containing the smallest first element will be first. In this case, the third list in the table, [3,5] has the smallest first element out of the rest, 3 < 4 and also < 7

I want to accomplish this with a simple for loop that involves swap so i attempted:

```
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    smallest = 0
    if lst[smallest][0] > lst[i][0]:
        lst[smallest],lst[i] = lst[i],lst[smallest]
```

but I'm getting the output of:

```
[[3,5],[5,2],[4,7]]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with grouping? You're just sorting, not grouping.

Comment: @everyone who answers this question: We have enough questions about sorting lists like these already. You don't have to post _another_ answer about `sorted` and key functions. If you're going to post an answer, please address and fix the bugs in the OP's code. Thanks.

Comment: @Aran-Fey SO provides a way to communicate that: (vote to) close as duplicate with a link to already answered questions.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I know. But the three people who posted answers don't seem to know. I don't think it's a duplicate because the OP is specifically asking for help fixing his loop. But people who post "hey, you can use `sorted`" as an answer don't have that excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1. You only iterate over the list once. There is no sorting algorithm that can sort a list just by iterating over it once - if you can do that, you have invented the world's first O(n) sorting algorithm. So you have to add another loop that loops until the list is correctly sorted.

   ```
   while True:
       changed = False

       for i in range(1,len(lst)):
           smallest = 0
           if lst[smallest][0] > lst[i][0]:
               lst[smallest],lst[i] = lst[i],lst[smallest]
               changed = True

       if not changed:
           break
   ```
2. You only ever swap bigger elements to the *first* position in the list. If the 2nd element is bigger than the 3rd element, your code can never swap them. Instead of hard-coding `smallest = 0`, you have to increment `smallest` with each iteration.

   ```
   for smallest in range(len(lst)):
       changed = False

       for i in range(1,len(lst)):
           if lst[smallest][0] > lst[i][0]:
               lst[smallest], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[smallest]
               changed = True

       if not changed:
           break
   ```
3. Now the code properly increments `smallest`, but it still loops over the *entire* list every time. So if `smallest` is an index pointing somewhere to the end of the list, the code still compares all the previous elements to the element at `smallest`. Obviously, the previous elements are already sorted - so they are guaranteed to be smaller than the element at `smallest`. Your code ends up swapping already sorted numbers, so the final result is no longer correctly sorted. You have to rewrite the inner loop so that it only loops over elements *after* `smallest`:

   ```
   for smallest in range(len(lst)):
       changed = False

       for i in range(smallest+1,len(lst)):  # changed 1 to smallest+1 here
           if lst[smallest][0] > lst[i][0]:
               lst[smallest], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[smallest]
               changed = True

       if not changed:
           break
   ```

With all these changes, we finally get a correct result:

```
[[3, 5], [4, 7], [5, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` already sorts lexicographically, so the simple command

```
>>> sorted([[5, 2], [4, 7], [3, 5]])
[[3, 5], [4, 7], [5, 2]]
```

is all you need.

Comment: i prefer using for loops. trying to reduce the dependency on sorted function.

Comment: @clink so in other words this is homework and `sorted` is off limits? :)

Comment: i wouldnt lie and say it's not homework. Its just a little fragment of the whole work I'm assigned to in the final stage of printing, hence, I'm working on a for loop to accomplish what i wanted.

Comment: @clink no problem. All you need to do then is pick any sorting algorithm and apply it to your problem. If speed is not a crucial issue start out with a bubblesort, for example.